# kotlin.Collections doesn't seem to be imported. "listOf" marked in red while in other proyect is working fine

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, methods, collections

My problem is that I can't use the method "listOf" even I was using it a while ago. I don't know what I did. In other proyect the method is working fine. I suspected the issue was related with dependencies, but then I realized the method belongs to "kotlin.Collections" which belongs to Kotlin Standard Library and this library seems to be imported in the background.

Sorry for my english. Please help!

Comment: What error do you get ? (in compile time or runtime)

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1cmq.png

Comment: Try Invalidate caches and restart, it'll try to re-index the kotlin standard library, if that didn't work, try to resync the gradle with latest Kotlin 1.4.0.

Comment: Thank you! It was related with the Kotlin version. It seems the Kotlin 1.3.72 version was having problems with the Kotlin Standard Library because in other project with 1.3.31 version was working fine.